# Как удалять слайды в slick slider при переходе на новую страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Есть главный slick slider внутри которого находятся изображения ведущие на новые страницы внутри которых также этот слайдер(что-то вроде навигации) Как при переходе на новую страницу с основного слайдера скрывать необходимые слайды в зависимости от перехода на новую страницу?

К примеру в слайдере есть изображение с авто, далее я перехожу с этого изображения на новую страницу внутри которой также слайдер, но у меня уже будет скрыт данный слайд на новой странице, т.к я нахожусь внутри конкретной страницы, на которой не нужно показывать конкретный слайд

```js
jQuery('.slick-slider').slick('slickRemove', jQuery("a[href=location.href]").parent().index()+1);
```

Comment: слайды то сами вы каким образом генерите?